# Remove files from history by specific extension

Tags: git

I have accidently committed files that shouldn't be in the repository. Now I want to remove this files from history.
What they have in common is, that they have the file extension *.test.

I tried to apply an index filter but that expects a specific file name.

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --chached --ignore-unmatch -r *.test' --prune-empty -- --all`

Is it possible to do this for all files in one step without specifying them manually?

Answer (score 12):

It's nearly unbelievable, but I had a typo in my script, but I think I have to escape the asterisk too.

So this script is working for me

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r \*.test' --prune-empty -- --all`